# Example of a function with an extremum that attains positive and negative values in the derivatives of a neighborhoud of the extremum.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to find a function such that:

- It has an extremum
- For any left and right neighbourhood of the extremum, the derivative attains both positive and negative values.

For the second condition, we can consider an oscillating function like $\sin{\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)}$. But I do not know how to modify this function for it to attain a maximum/minimum at some point.

Comment: Should this function $x^2+x^2Sin(1/x)$ solve your question?

Comment: @TitoEliatron How would you show that this has a minimum at $x=0$?

Comment: $f(x)=x^2(1+\sin(1/x))\ge 0$ and $f(0):=\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0$. So $x=0$ is a the global minimum.